# update DataGridView column value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to update value of specific column of `datagridview` while 
looping on it by getting the `DGV_1.CurrentRow.Index`  and pass it to method, but the update cell is only the first cell on the column it is not moving to next row at `datagridview`.

I noticed that the index has value of 1 or 0 so why?
I tried to use the count of rows but that will update the last row only instead of first record.
I slos noticed that happen because of that selection stay at first record .
I tried to change the selection to next record while I am looping but I fail.

```
public void DataGridViewLoop()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow OfficeListRow in DGV_OfficeList.Rows)
        {
            int RowNum = DGV_OfficeList.CurrentRow.Index;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow FileListRow in DGV_FileList.Rows)
            {
                // do something then  ... 
                UpdateDGVcolumn(RowNum);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}


public void UpdateDGVcolumn(int RowNum)
{
    DGV_OfficeList[4, RowNum].Value = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: If you use `CurrentRow.Index`, it would always update the current row,obviously. Try `int RowNum = OfficeListRow.Index;`

Comment: @Pikoh yes I tried to change the selection to next record while I am looping but I fail

Comment: Try the code I've told you, and see if that works

Comment: @Pikoh thanks problem solved if you wish to post it as answer and ill mark it

Comment: Glad it helped. I posted the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `CurrentRow.Index`, it would always update the current row,obviously. Try `int RowNum = OfficeListRow.Index;`

Also notice that the second `foreach` looping `DGV_FileList` is not necessary.

Comment: the second foreach loop on another datagridview ;)
the frist one loop on DGV_OfficeList and the second loop on DGV_FileList
am I right my friend ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 //Loop over rows

 for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    //Use when column names known
    datagridview.Rows[i].Cells["columnName"].Value  = value;
    //Use when column index known
    datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value  = value;   
 }
```

Comment: You should change rowNumber to i

Comment: Correct. Should have checked before posting.